# Create view by pulling data from three tables

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I know this questions has been asked several times, however it did not solve my question.

I have three tables, JD, LYR and VC ,all three have different schema. I want to create a view that will pull data from these three tables such that, it will have record that is present in JD and LYR and also in LYR and VC. So, I think there should be inner join between JD/LYR and LYR/VC. I do not want to join JD and VC.

I wrote the sql, however, if it shows the record that is present in JD and LYR, then it will not show the matching record between LYR and VC and vice versa. My current SQL is as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
SELECT JD.REQ_ID,
       JD.REF_NO,
       LYR.OID_VAL,
       VC.ACCOUNT_STATUS,
       VC.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM JD 
INNER JOIN LYR
    ON (JD.REQ_ID = LYR.REQ_ID)
INNER JOIN VC
    ON LYR.REQ_ID = VC.REQUEST_ID;
```

I tried and changed the join types to other joins like Left outer etc, but did not work.Any help will be appreciated regarding the SQL for this view.

Thanks in advance,
KB.

Comment: You select jd, lyr and vcase columns, from jd, lyr and vc...

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data and expected output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: According to your description you have all the records in `LYR` and both the tables `JD` & `VC` have some shared data from this table. But `JD` & `VC` may or may not have same data so in this case you have to do `LEFT JOIN` with `LYR` as main table as given below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
SELECT JD.REQ_ID,
       JD.REF_NO,
       LYR.OID_VAL,
       VCASE.ACCOUNT_STATUS,
       VCASE.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM LYR 
LEFT JOIN JD ON JD.REQ_ID = LYR.REQ_ID
LEFT JOIN VC  ON LYR.REQ_ID = VC.REQUEST_ID;
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick help. I followed Suraz suggestions and seems like it is working, I will do more checking later on.

Comment: Will this avoid selecting rows in LYR where there is no matching row in neither JD nor VC?

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like Below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
SELECT * FROM (SELECT JD.REQ_ID,JD.REF_NO,LYR.OID_VAL,VCASE.ACCOUNT_STATUS,VCASE.ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
FROM JD INNER JOIN LYR ON (JD.REQ_ID = LYR.REQ_ID)) a INNER JOIN VC
ON a.REQ_ID = VC.REQUEST_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current sql will show records only where data is present in all three tables.  It sounds to me like you want sql that will show data present in certain kinds of outer joins.

A first version would be to write the query as a UNION rather than  JOIN (i.e. two queries with a single inner join in them and a UNION ALL between them). This would be to guarantee correctness.

From there you may be able to create something using outer joins and where conditions which may perform better, but it is usually best to ensure correctness first.

Answer (score 0):

Since your query inner-joins all three tables, it will only show a record where there is matching data in all three tables. As I understand it, you want record to be shown where there is matching data in `LYR` and `JD` *or* in `LYR` and `VC` (or in all three).

I'm not aware of a way to do this directly using joins, so I'd left-join them with an additional condition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
SELECT JD.REQ_ID,
       JD.REF_NO,
       LYR.OID_VAL,
       VCASE.ACCOUNT_STATUS,
       VCASE.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM LYR
LEFT JOIN JD
    ON (LYR.REQ_ID = JD.REQ_ID)
LEFT JOIN VC
    ON (LYR.REQ_ID = VC.REQUEST_ID)
WHERE JD.REQ_ID IS NOT NULL OR VC.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

Another possible approach would be to use `UNION` (and *not* `UNION ALL`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
SELECT JD.REQ_ID,
       JD.REF_NO,
       LYR.OID_VAL,
       VCASE.ACCOUNT_STATUS,
       VCASE.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM LYR
INNER JOIN JD
    ON (LYR.REQ_ID = JD.REQ_ID)
LEFT JOIN VC
    ON (LYR.REQ_ID = VC.REQUEST_ID)
UNION
SELECT JD.REQ_ID,
       JD.REF_NO,
       LYR.OID_VAL,
       VCASE.ACCOUNT_STATUS,
       VCASE.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM LYR
INNER JOIN VC
    ON (LYR.REQ_ID = VC.REQUEST_ID)
LEFT JOIN JD
    ON (LYR.REQ_ID = JD.REQ_ID);
```

Comment: Thank you Jiri Tousek for the help. Appreicate it. Your sql also worked, it is just a bit more SQL due to union and I have tons of fields in all of the three tables, so it will be huge code to work on. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

If the table have got matching number of colums do this:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS (
select * from JD
union all
select * from LYR
union all
select * from VC
);